# Как расположить gridView в relativelayout?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно расположить нижний gridView, чтобы он был по центру верхнего View, но так чтобы он был на 15 dp больше слева и справа.

```
    <GridView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:verticalSpacing="7dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу чтобы было так

Comment: Я нифига не понял что вы имеете в виду. Попробуйте переформулировать желаемое расположение.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, обновил выше

Comment: Ну... Можно попробовать верхнему марджины по 15 и гравити центр. Нижнему туже гравити и 0 марджина. Обоим ширину match_parant. Но, думаю, вам не совсем то надо и вы сейчас ещё раз вопрос уточните.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а теперь я ничего не поняЛ_

Comment: Вы в xml никак не сможете задать цифрами ширину одного элемента относительно другого. Надо как-то иначе.

Comment: Моя идея - не нижний делать больше, а верхнему отступы дать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я сделал как вы сказали, но суть такая что нижний View не считает margin верхнего. В этом и рпоблема

Comment: Я вас немного не понял. Если верхний займёт всю ширину экрана минус отступы, то он будет на отступы по ширине меньше нижнего (который без отступов). Это как раз должно заявленное реализовать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32330/discussion-between-xtigrx-and-).